# Raspberry Pi IBeacon no such device

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, ibeacon, bluez

I´m trying to set up my Raspberry as an IBeacon. When I run:

```
sudo hcitool scan
```

it outputs

```
Device is not available: No such device
```

If I run `lsusb` I get an output like this

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:100b Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
```

where `Device005` is my bt dongle

While searching the web for solutions, I noticed that everybody else's output was like this:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, **Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)**
```

Also,

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth status
```

outputs

```
[ ok ] bluetooth is running.
```

I don't know what to do here. Been trying to figure this out for weeks.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to change the USB mode of the device from a startup one to an operational one, at which point the product ID would change.  See http://blog.ruecker.fi/2013/10/06/adventures-in-bluetooth-4-0-part-i/ for someone else's experience.

Answer (score 1):

Your Bluetooth dongle is probably not compatible with the Linux Bluez stack, or you don't have the proper driver installed.  If you want to solve this the easy way, get a replacement dongle.  This one is known to work and costs less than $14: [http://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-Bluetooth-Micro-Adapter-GBU521/dp/B007GFX0PY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007GFX0PY)

If you want to solve this the hard way, you need to start researching drivers for the dongle you have.  A first step along this path would be to post the manufacturer and model number of the device you are using.